# Declarar scripts en vistas parciales en ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Estoy trabajando con ASP.NET MVC, JQuery, Javascript

Tengo entendido que cuando se trabaja con una vista principal que llama a una vista parcial, la vista parcial se inyecta en la vista principal. Si eso fuera cierto ya no sería necesario declarar los scripts de validación en la vista parcial, como:

```
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

En otras palabras o dicho de otra manera ¿es necesario declarar los mismos scripts en la vista parcial, habiendo antes haber declarado en la vista principal?

Comment: Parece que faltó incluir algo entre "... la vista parcial, como:" y "No creo que...". Por otro lado, considero que ñas preguntas del tipo "no creo que sea una pregunta muy amplia", son mas apropiadas para [meta] o para el chat, ya que en el sitio principal no van discusiones (no es un foro).

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente, cuando se usan vistas parciales, ya sea con `Html.Partial()` o con `Html.Action()`, no es necesario declarar los scripts que se usen en la página que las invoca, solamente los que no.

Eso sí, en general es mejor no tener scripts en las vistas parciales por simplicidad.